# Ubuntu karmic doesn't have the version file?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I was following this tutorial: http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/4/23/ubuntu-karmic-setup-part-2

On my ubuntu karmic version (on ec2, ami from elastic) I don't see this file:

cat /etc/lsb-release

It just isn't there.

How can I see the version of the O/S? And shouldn't that file be there?

Some people have told me ubuntu isn't really used as a server, is that true or is the trend making it more viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue the command `lsb_release -a`

Comment: so I guess the location is different?